# Weekly with Hourly Tide Chart using HighChart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am new to `HighChart Js`, I want a Tidechart to be plotted in HighCharts.

I need some output like below screenshot:
[Chart Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHo12.jpg)

I have tried the below link : [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/d8yo6t19/)

but i am getting the result as : [MyCodeResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrVRF.png)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'line'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Weekly Tide Chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
    title: {
      text: 'Day of the Week'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Tide Level'
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: '12 AM',
      data: [3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 2.9, 2.4, 3.1, 3.6] // Will be Replaced with my actual tide data for each hour of the day (e.g., Monday, 12 AM)
    },
    {
      name: '1 AM',
      data: [3.1, 3.3, 3.7, 2.8, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5] // Will be Replaced with my actual tide data for each hour of the day (e.g., Monday, 1 AM)
    },
    // Will Repeat the above data series for each hour of the day (e.g., 2 AM, 3 AM, ..., 11 PM)
  ]
});
```

Could anyone please help me what I did wrong or correct me would be appreciated.

Comment: Please also add the results of what you have tried in your question

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d8yo6t19/  I have tried here and result got in 2 different waves instead of 1 wave.

Answer (score 0):

For tide-styled line, use the `spline` series type:

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wLbqt5np/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.spline